# Sumar una cantidad de dias u otra si se cumple o no una condicion

Tags: php, if, foreach, else

Intento que se sumen una cantidad de dias u otra en función de que el campo Fecha_Pendiente este establecido.

Si lo está se suman 30 días a esa fecha.
Si no lo está se suman 15 días a la Fecha_Apertura.

No consigo que funcione, pienso que el problema está en la condicion.

```
    <?php 

try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basedatos', 'user', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$fechas = $conexion->prepare("
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM incidencias
    LIMIT 10
    ");

$fechas->execute();
$fechas = $fechas->fetchAll();

echo $fechas;



fecha1 = date('Y-m-j');
$fecha1 = $fecha['Fecha_Apertura'];
$nuevafecha1 = strtotime ( '+15 day' , strtotime ( $fecha1 ) ) ;
$nuevafecha1 = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $nuevafecha1 );

fecha2 = date('Y-m-j');
$fecha2 = $fecha['Fecha_Pendiente'];
$nuevafecha2 = strtotime ( '+30 day' , strtotime ( $fecha2 ) ) ;
$nuevafecha2 = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $nuevafecha2 );

?> 



<div class="contenedor">
    <h1>Fechas</h1>
    <section class="fechas">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($fechas as $fecha){
             if (!$fecha['Fecha_Pendiente']) {
                $fecha3 = $nuevafecha1;
                } else{
                $fecha3 = $nuevafecha2;
            }
            } ?>
                <li><?php echo $fecha['Fecha_Apertura'] . '//' . $fecha['Fecha_Pendiente'] . '//' . $fecha3 ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

Gracias

Conseguido:

La idea es: Si la Fecha de Ultima reclamacion no es =0 debe sumar 30 dias a esta fecha y mostrarlo en Próximo Update. Si es 0 debe sumar 15 días a la Fecha de Apertura.

```
    <?php 

    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basedatos', 'user', 'password');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

    $fechas = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM CSC_Navegaciones LIMIT 10");

    $fechas->execute();
    $fechas = $fechas->fetchAll();

    ?> 

    <div class="contenedor">
        <h1>Fechas</h1>
        <section class="fechas">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($fechas as $fecha):
                    $fecha1 = date('Y-m-d');
                    $fecha1 = $fecha['Fecha_Apertura'];
                    $nuevafecha1 = strtotime ( '+15 day' , strtotime ( $fecha1 ) ) ;
                    $nuevafecha1 = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $nuevafecha1 );

                    $fecha2 = date('Y-m-j');
                    $fecha2 = $fecha['Fecha_Ultima_Reclam'];
                    $nuevafecha2 = strtotime ( '+30 day' , strtotime ( $fecha2 ) ) ;
                    $nuevafecha2 = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $nuevafecha2 );

                    if ($fecha2 != 0){$nuevafecha = $nuevafecha2;
                    }
                        else{ $nuevafecha = $nuevafecha1;
                        }

                ?>
                    <span> Fecha de Apertura    ||| Fecha Ultima Reclamacion ||| Fecha Proximo Update</span>
                    <li><?php echo $fecha['Fecha_Apertura'] . ' |||| ' . $fecha['Fecha_Ultima_Reclam'] . ' ||| ' . $nuevafecha ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>    
            </ul>       

    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona en sí? ¿Has ido depurando los valores de cada variable?

Comment: Hola A.Cedano, Gracias por tu respuesta. He vuelto a revisar el codigo, y había errores de escritura en 2 variables, Ahora muestra resultados, voy a seguír dándole vueltas a ver si consigo que haga lo que quiero. te informo si lo consigo como si no.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, Ya he conseguido que haga lo que quería. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Edito arriba con el codigo correcto.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas conseguido. Saludos.